# Querying Access database through pyodbc sometimes works fine, but sometimes gives connection error

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to execute SQL query in a locally stored Access database through `pyodbc`.

In the code below, printing the table names works fine, so the connection seems to be established successfully:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=O:\MAP\05_Reporting\2018_MAPDB_NewServer.accdb;'
    r'PWD=some_password;'
    r'UID=some_login;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def get_table_names():
    table_names = (table_info.table_name for table_info in cnxn.cursor().tables())
    return table_names

def get_query():
    sql = "SELECT MAID FROM dbo_MAMain"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    query = cursor.fetchall()
    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_names = get_table_names()
    for table_name in table_names:
        print(table_name) # this works fine

    query = get_query() # this gives a connection error
    print(query)
```

However, the `query = get_query()` line will throw an error that indicates something opposite:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 28, in
>   
>       query = get_query()   File "test.py", line 19, in get_query
>       cursor.execute(sql) pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] ODBC--connection to
>   'MAP_SQL_2014' failed. (-2001) (SQLExecDirectW)")

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Try calling `pyodbc.pooling = False` before calling `pyodbc.connect`.

Comment: @GordThompson: Sadly, I still get the same error.

Comment: When you try opening the "dbo_MAMain" table from within MS Access itself are you prompted for a username and password?

Comment: Not for this table specifically, but in general yes, I have to provide username and password (the same I use in the code above) when I try to access any of the database's tables, queries etc.

Comment: Immediately after `cursor = cnxn.cursor()` try `cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM [ODBC;DSN=MAP_SQL_2014;UID=some_login;PWD=some_password].sys.tables")`. That may establish the pass-through connection from ACE to SQL_Server and allow the subsequent linked-table queries to run.

Comment: @GordThompson: Unfortunately, the very same error is now being thrown at the `cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*)...` line that I have added as you suggested.